# Memory alignment in C-structs

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-alignment, structure-packing

I'm working on a 32-bit machine, so I suppose that the memory alignment should be 4 bytes. Say I have this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short v1;
    unsigned short v2;
    unsigned short v3;
} myStruct;
```

The plain added size is 6 bytes, and I suppose that the aligned size should be 8, but `sizeof(myStruct)` returns me 6.

However if I write:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short v1;
    unsigned short v2;
    unsigned short v3;
    int i;
} myStruct;
```

the plain added size is 10 bytes, aligned size shall be 12, and this time `sizeof(myStruct) == 12`.

Can somebody explain what is the difference?

Comment: sizeof DOES include the padding, otherwise it would be useless for copy the struct - the whole point of sizeof is to tell you the actual size in memory

Comment: possible duplicate of [struct padding in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

At least on most machines, a type is only ever aligned to a boundary as large as the type itself [Edit: you can't really demand any "more" alignment than that, because you have to be able to create arrays, and you can't insert padding into an array]. On your implementation, `short` is apparently 2 bytes, and `int` 4 bytes.

That means your first struct is aligned to a 2-byte boundary. Since all the members are 2 bytes apiece, no padding is inserted between them.

The second contains a 4-byte item, which gets aligned to a 4-byte boundary. Since it's preceded by 6 bytes, 2 bytes of padding is inserted between `v3` and `i`, giving 6 bytes of data in the `short`s, two bytes of padding, and 4 more bytes of data in the `int` for a total of 12.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I choose this answer, cause it was first correct. So compiler aligns the struct to the size of the largest element.

Comment: @Ivan technically it aligns to the largest *alignment* of any item in the struct (which is subtly different than what you said).

Comment: How does it behave in _arrays_ of such structs? Have we proportional memory loss here?

Comment: @VitalikVerhovodov: An array can't have padding between items, so an array of N items always has a size exactly N * the size of a single item.

Comment: @Ivan You cannot make general assumptions (independent of CPU/compiler/options) about member alignment. There may or may not be padding, and if there is, it may or may not be to the byte boundary corresponding to the member size. A compiler is free to pad more than the type size in structs even if it cannot do so in arrays. (I don't know whether that happens anywhere in reality, but on a 64 bit machine it is not inconceivable that 64 bit aligned access may be the fastest, so a struct of 4 chars may have a size of 32 bytes --  as would have a struct of 4 shorts or 4 ints.)

Comment: "*At least on most machines, a type is only ever aligned to a boundary as large as the type itself [Edit: you can't really demand any "more" alignment than that*" --- While this is true, I think you only implicitly focused on some of the crucial confusions of the OP: "*I'm working on a 32-bit machine, so I suppose that the memory alignment should be 4 bytes.*" - OP thinks/thought (doesn't really matter if he already understood it - it's important for anyone who come here) that there is something like a generic alignment based upon the architecture. You should cover that part at least a little.

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure if you answered [Vitalik's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435841/memory-alignment-in-c-structs#comment45993654_5435890) in the way s/he meant it. I can read it as s/he asks if padding *inside of* the structures is happening too if one has an array of these structures, so that each structure element has a padded piece.

Answer (score 23):

Forget about having different members, even if you write two structs whose members are *exactly* same, with **a difference** is that the order in which they're declared is different, then size of each struct can be (and often is) different.

For example, see this,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
   char c;
   char d;
   int i; 
};
struct B
{
   char c;
   int i;   //note the order is different!
   char d;
};
int main() {
        cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
        cout << sizeof(B) << endl;
}
```

Compile it with `gcc-4.3.4`, and you get this output:

```
8
12
```

That is, sizes are different even though both structs has same members!

Code at Ideone  : http://ideone.com/HGGVl

The bottomline is that the Standard doesn't talk about how padding should be done, and so the compilers are free to make any decision and you **cannot** assume all compilers make the same decision.

Comment: Hm, is this splitting hairs now? Event with gcc4.3.4, you can get different results on another platform (we used gcc on a TI DSP quite a while ago where sizeof(char) == sizeof(int) and CHAR_BIT == 16. Sure, *there* you could have played the same game with int and long...).

Comment: "*Compile it with `gcc-4.3.4`, and you get this output:*" is indeed completely wrong and confusing for novices. You cannot assume that every implementation has the same alignment requirements just because using the same compiler. Your concern about that order is important too is excellent but the impression that a compiler always gives the same result is inappropriate and wrong -1 until you change it.

Answer (score 13):

By default, values are aligned according to their size.  So a 2-byte value like a `short` is aligned on a 2-byte boundary, and a 4-byte value like an `int` is aligned on a 4-byte boundary

In your example, 2 bytes of padding are added before `i` to ensure that `i` falls on a 4-byte boundary.

(The entire structure is aligned on a boundary at least as big as the biggest value in the structure, so your structure will be aligned to a 4-byte boundary.)

The actual rules vary according to the platform - the Wikipedia page on [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) has more details.

Compilers typically let you control the packing via (for example) `#pragma pack` directives.

Comment: I would like to understand why a short is aligned by a 2-bytes boundary. From an optimization point of view, with avoiding a datum ocuppies two differente 4-bytes words is enough. For example, why not a structure like that: `struct C { int i:8; char c; int j:8; };`?

Comment: @Peregring-lk You probably shall (if not done yet) dedicate a separate question to this.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming:

```
sizeof(unsigned short) == 2
sizeof(int)            == 4
```

Then I personally would use the following (your compiler may differ):

```
unsigned shorts are aligned to 2 byte boundaries
int will be aligned to 4 byte boundaries.


typedef struct
{
   unsigned short v1;    // 0 bytes offset
   unsigned short v2;    // 2 bytes offset
   unsigned short v3;    // 4 bytes offset
} myStruct;              // End 6 bytes.


// No part is required to align tighter than 2 bytes. 
// So whole structure can be 2 byte aligned.

typedef struct
{
    unsigned short v1;      // 0 bytes offset
    unsigned short v2;      // 2 bytes offset
    unsigned short v3;      // 4 bytes offset
    /// Padding             // 6-7 padding (so i is 4 byte aligned)
    int i;                  // 8 bytes offset
} myStruct;                 // End 12 bytes

// Whole structure needs to be 4 byte aligned.
// So that i is correctly aligned.
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, while the specifics of padding are left up to the compiler, the OS also imposes some rules as to alignment requirements. This answer assumes that you are using gcc, though the OS may vary

To determine the space occupied by a given struct and its elements, you can follow these rules:

First, assume that the struct always starts at an address that is properly aligned for *all* data types.

Then for every entry in the struct:

- The minimum space needed is the raw size of the element given by `sizeof(element)`.
- The alignment requirement of the element is the alignment requirement of the element's base type.
  Notably, this means that the alignment requirement for a `char[20]` array is the same as
  the requirement for a plain `char`.

Finally, the alignment requirement of the struct as a whole is the maximum of the alignment requirements of each of its elements.

gcc will insert padding after a given element to ensure that the next one (or the struct if we are talking about the last element) is correctly aligned. It will *never* rearrange the order of the elements in the struct, even if that will save memory.

Now the alignment requirements themselves are also a bit odd.

- 32-bit Linux requires that 2-byte data types have 2-byte alignment (their addresses must be even). All larger data types must have 4-byte alignment (addresses ending in `0x0`, `0x4`, `0x8` or `0xC`). Note that this applies to types larger than 4 bytes as well (such as `double` and `long double`).
- 32-bit Windows is more strict in that if a type is K bytes in size, it must be K byte aligned. This means that a `double` can only placed at an address ending in `0x0` or `0x8`. The only exception to this is the `long double` which is still 4-byte aligned even though it is actually 12-bytes long.
- For both Linux and Windows, on 64-bit machines, a K byte type must be K byte aligned. Again, the `long double` is an exception and must be 16-byte aligned.

Answer (score 4):

Each data type needs to be aligned on a memory boundary of its own size. So a `short` needs to be on aligned on a 2-byte boundary, and an `int` needs to be on a 4-byte boundary. Similarly, a `long long` would need to be on an 8-byte boundary.

Comment: no, it doesn't need to - it's just compiled like that to produce faster code (look at pragma packed in gcc)

Comment: @fazo Technically the compiler can generate code to access unaligned memory, but it requires multiple load instructions and some combination instructions, as the processor will not allow you to load unaligned data in one operation. That is why you need to explicitly tell it to not pad. Your best option is to put the largest types first, so no padding is necessary.

Comment: @Johathan: that depends on the processor. An x86 (for one obvious example) can handle mis-aligned accesses entirely in hardware -- all of the multiple reads (if necessary) and assembly is handled in the hardware.

Comment: And on the other end of the scale, hardware like SPARC will generate a bus error if you access mis-aligned variables.

Comment: So basically, it's best not to do it :-P

Comment: Some processors will allow it, but you take a performance hit while the CPU faults and reassembles the data for you into a register.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the second `sizeof(myStruct)` being `12` is the padding that gets inserted between `v3` and `i` to align `i` at a 32-bit boundary. There is two bytes of it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) explains the padding and alignment reasonably clearly.

Comment: So you mean `sizeof` calculates the padding between the vars, but not the alignment bytes at the end/beginning of the struct?

Comment: yes, I suppose that it has to return me alignment bytes at the end/beginning

Comment: @Ivan Your first struct *is* aligned. The alignment there is on a 2-byte boundary, since that's the size of the largest element of the struct. The second struct is aligned on a 4-byte boundary (because of the int). Neither needs any padding at the beginning or end.

Comment: @Hossein `sizeof` includes both the padding inside the struct and at the end. The size `myStruct` is 6 bytes since there are no padding at the end of the struct. The reason for this is that you don't need it since it only contains members that require 2-byte alignment.

Answer (score 2):

In your first struct, since every item is of size `short`, the whole struct can be aligned on `short` boundaries, so it doesn't need to add any padding at the end.

In the second struct, the int (presumably 32 bits) needs to be word aligned so it inserts padding between `v3` and `i` to align `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't say much about the layout of structs with complete types - it's up to to the compiler. It decided that it needs the int to start on a boundary to access it, but since it has to do sub-boundary memory addressing for the shorts there is no need to pad them

Comment: Could I get a source on this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its being aligned to bounderies based on the size of each var, so that the address is a multiple of the size being accessed(so shorts are aligned to 2, ints aligned to 4 etc), if you moved one of the shorts after the int, `sizeof(mystruct)` should be 10. Of course this all depends on the compiler being used and what settings its using in turn.