# address assignment of class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have 2 classes which are,

```
#define    HEADER_SIZE    sizeof(CHeader)
#define    BODY_SIZE      5132  
#define    PACKET_SIZE    sizeof(CPacket)  

Class CHeader
{
    BYTE    a;
    BYTE    b;
    long    c;
    long    d;
}

Class CPacket : CObject
{

    CHeader mHeader;
    BYTE    mBody[BODY_SIZE];

    CPacket() {    }
    virtual ~CPacket() {    }
}
```

In other class' function, I have

```
void func()
{
    BYTE    mRcvData[PACKET_SIZE];

    CPacket   *packet = new CPacket();

    memcpy(packet->mHeader, mRcvData, HEADER_SIZE);
}
```

mRcvData is received from client by socket so I want to save the data into CPacket instance. To copy the header part of mRcvData into packet first, I used "memcpy" function as above but it didn't work.

My question will be,

First, how can I make it work as I intended?

Second, how is the member variables' address assigned in the CHeader Class and CPacket?
If I assigned "long c" after "BYTE b" like above, "long c" will have the address of "BYTE b"+1 ?

I mean, my logic is, for example,

```
Address of CHEADER Class : @ 1000

Address of variable "a" in CHEADER Class : @ 1000

Address of variable "b" in CHEADER Class : @ 1001 (because "a" consumes 1 byte)

Address of variable "c" in CHEADER Class : @ 1002 (because "b" consumes 1 byte)

Address of variable "d" in CHEADER Class : @ 1006 (because "c" consumes 4 byte)
```

Is it true? what about "CPacket class"?

Comment: Let me give you a suggestion: Don't use macros, use `const`

Comment: And another. post *real* code. None o this compiles, so asking us to spot *thse* specific error amongst the chaos isn't constructive.

Comment: You're trying too hard. Let the compiler do the hard work. Use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: Is there any disadvantage if i use macros instead of const?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "long c" will have the address of "BYTE b"+1 ?

In most cases no, because the compiler might add padding to the byte `a` and `b` so that they will both fit in 4 bytes resulting in a total of 12 bytes for `CHeader` instead of 10 (optimizations). As a result doing memcpy and manually assigning bytes to members will not yeld the same result. see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for more details.

If you want to assign bytes directly (which i believe is labeled as undefined behavior) you can do:

```
BYTE    mRcvData[PACKET_SIZE];
CPacket   *packet = new CPacket();
packet->header = reinterpret_cast<CHeader*>(&mRcvData[0]);//let the compiler do memcpy for you
//memcpy only on the body
memcpy( packet->mBody, &mRcvData[sizeof(CHeader)] , min(PACKET_SIZE - sizeof(CHeader), BODY_SIZE) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about member's adress is wrong. 
The compiler MIGHT insert some padding, in order to preserve memory alignment [1].

That's why your memcpy doesen't work. You must take chunks of mRcvData and assign to members of packet->mHeader, member by member.

[1] - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

[2] - [Memory alignment in C-structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435841/memory-alignment-in-c-structs) (even it's about C structs, the rules ar the same in c++).

Comment: The padding might be controled with #pragma pack(n) on a MS compiler. Others have similar pargmas

Comment: I used "pragma pack" and it also works. is there any side effect or something to be careful for using this?