# Size of structures and variables

Tags: c

I am a bit lost on calculating the size of structures

So we have the structure:

```
struct AcronymNode{ 
    struct AcronymNode* next; 
    char acronym[5]; 
    double num_phrases; 
    struct The_Phrase* phrase_list; 
    } Dictionary;
```

I see it as

```
next : 4bytes
acronym: 5bytes + 3
num_phrases: 8bytes
phraselist: 4bytes
=24 bytes
```

When I look at the notes it says: 32 bytes = 4 + 5 + 3 (alignment to 
word) + 4 (to align for the double) + 8 + 4 + 4 (to align next structure to a multiple of 8 for 
the double)

Why are we adding an extra 8 for alignment since it doesn't overflow, 4 before the double and 4 after the 2nd structure

In the more efficient structure it has double first, following the structures for 24 bytes

Also I wanted to check if this is right

```
structT{
    int a;
    char b[5];
    float c;
    char d[2];
    };
```

Is the size 4 + 5+3 + 4 + 4 = 20?

Comment: Alignment is added for performance reasons. If you don't want it, use __attribute__((packed)) (gcc/clang). Also, compiler is not going to reorder fields for you, it's your responsibility.

Comment: This wikipedia page is a good source of information on why padding is added : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment. There are nice examples on x86 architecture.

Comment: This is caused by the compiler trying to align object to match address boundaries that are appropriate for a type. Take a look at [Memory alignment in C-structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435841/memory-alignment-in-c-structs).

Comment: What notes are you talking about? Give the link.

Comment: @Barmar this is from a sample exam

Comment: So? I still think the answer in the other question will explain what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory access latency is not something you are concerned with, you can instruct the compiler to layout a structure on a different alignment (than that which is most efficient for the machine).  For example:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct AcronymNode{ 
    struct AcronymNode* next; 
    char acronym[5]; 
    double num_phrases; 
    struct The_Phrase* phrase_list; 
    } Dictionary;
#pragma pack()
```

Although '#pragma pack' is not officially part of the C language, it is supported by most compilers.  In the example above, '#pragma pack(1)' instructs the compiler to pack the structure on a one-byte boundaries, effectively changing the layout of the structure as you described it:

```
next : 4bytes
acronym: 5bytes + 3
num_phrases: 8bytes
phraselist: 4bytes
=24 bytes
```

Then, '#pragma pack()' returns alignment back to it's default.

```
.
```

'#pragma pack(1)' is often used to define structures where other alignments are not desirable; for example, when sending such structures "over the wire" to another system.  Wire protocols are generally packed so that there is no filler between fields.

Answer (score 0):

packing structs to a 1 byte boundary is used to optimize for space, otherwise the compiler will pad out for speed performance.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding