# C generic inheritance with low verbosity

Tags: c, unions

Having:

```
struct packet_sample_t {
   int common_id;
   int some;
   char data[];
   float foo;
}
```

Having the following function:

```
void dispatch_packet(void *packet);
```

My goal would be to parse the packet id and then call its handler, but I can't retrieve the struct variable `common_id` from `void *`.

I would like to create something like an `interface` in hight level languages, assuming that all my packets structures should have the variable `common_id`.
So I'm looking something that would work like below:

```
struct packet_base {
   int common_id;
}

void dispatch_packet(void *packet) {
   int common_id = ( (packet_base *)packet )->common_id;
   switch(common_id) {...}
}

void test() {
   packet_sample_t packet = {.common_id = 10, ...};
   dispatch_packet((void *) &packet); //this function should retrieve `common_id`

   packet_other_t other = {.common_id = 1};
   dispatch_packet((void *) &other); // again with another packet
}
```

Im not that familiar to C language and I dont really know how I could do this. But in simple words, I would like to be able to cast a packet to its packet_base, that are sharing both a common variable.

EDIT: more details in the example

Comment: You can freely cast any object pointer type to and from `void*` as long as it is actually pointing to the data of that type...

Comment: ye but a `packet_sample_t` is not a `packet_base_t`

Comment: I see. Take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252552/why-do-we-need-c-unions Pretty much about your case

Comment: I would try to not use void pointers. Give the compiler a chance and help you as much as possible

Comment: @EugeneSh. Could you provide an example related to my topic? I can't apply the unions to my need.. That's why I asked this question

Comment: Ok, wait up....

Comment: When you pass a `packet_sample_t` pointer into `dispatch_packet`, and inside that function you cast it to a `struct packet` pointer in order to get the `common_id`, the input parameter packet is still pointing to the `struct packet_sample_t` that was passed in, so when you call whatever function you need in the dispatcher, the memory is still intact.

Comment: I cannot find any union in your code?

Comment: ye my function `dispatch_packet` is generic and has to workd for all packets I will make. And they are both having the variable `int common_id`

Comment: @klutt you're right, I know my problem can be resolved by an union but I can't apply it to my request

Comment: Or maybe could I do a tricky thing, like.. memcpy the first bytes of my `void *` into a `packet_base *` assuming all packets got at the begin of their struct the `common_id` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technique is valid. There's [a number of ways to do struct inheritance in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114349/struct-inheritance-in-c#1114362), and this is one of them. [*21st Century C*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025108.do) might be a good read for you as well as [*Object-Oriented Programming with ANSI C*](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf).

You have a problems with how you're declaring and using your structs and types. Let's look at this.

```
struct packet_base {
   int common_id;
};
```

This has the type `struct packet_base`. If you want to declare a pointer to this type you need to write `struct packet_base *packet`. If you want to cast a variable of this type it's `(struct packet_base *)thing`.

This is annoying, so you typically declare a type alias to the struct using `typedef`. The syntax is `typedef <type> <alias>`

```
typedef struct {
   int common_id;
} packet_base_t;
```

That says the type `struct { int common_id; }` is aliased to `packet_base_t`. Now you can use `packet_base_t` as the type. `packet_base_t *packet` declares a pointer and `(packet_base_t *)thing` casts.

With that fixed, plus some small errors, it works. See [What is the difference between char array vs char pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186765/what-is-the-difference-between-char-array-vs-char-pointer-in-c#10186799) for `char *data` vs `char data[]`.

```
typedef struct {
   int common_id;
   int some;
   char *data;
   float foo;
} packet_sample_t;

typedef struct {
   int common_id;
} packet_base_t;

void dispatch_packet(void *arg) {
    // It's simpler to cast to a new variable once then to muck
    // up the code with casts.
    packet_base_t *packet = (packet_base_t *)arg;

    int common_id = packet->common_id;
    printf("id: %d\n", common_id);
}
```

Comment: assuming `common_id` is always at the top of each packet?

Comment: "Your technique is valid". Unfortunately the C standard doesn't seem to share this optimism.

Comment: @lordjj Yes. The technique relies on derived structs having the same memory layout as the base. Assuming 64 bit integers, `packet->common_id` basically says "get me the first 64 bits in the memory `packet` points to". [There are complications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435841/memory-alignment-in-c-structs#5435890).

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, but it's a thing people seem to get away with. Perl 5 relies heavily on this technique. As for really doing polymorphism in C, I defer to whatever "*21st Century C*" says.

Comment: @Schwern I see, this is so dope, I didn't expect that my sample code was about to work or even compile XD

Comment: "it's a thing people seem to get away with" true fact!

Comment: @lordjj This technique will only get you so far before it gets messy. You'll want to look into vtables and n.m.'s struct embedding technique as an alternative. Or use a more sophisticated language that already supports inheritance (or inheritance-like things) such as C++, Go, or Rust.

Comment: @Schwern `__attribute__((__packed__))` should fix the problem of padding, right?

Comment: but is the padding problem appliable on my example?

Comment: @Schwern :( ? sorry but could u reply

Comment: @lordjj I don't know much about padding issues, just that it's a gotcha with this technique. You'll have to ask another question. Also, Object-oriented programming and polymorphism in C is a very large and complex topic and I recommend you don't tackle it if you're new to C. I'd recommend reading those books I recommended and various other questions here about OOP in C. And consider whether C is the right language for your project.

Comment: I read about, and `__attribute__((__packed__)) ` after the `struct` keyword will solve the padding issue, assuming the compilation is performed by gcc or clang ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union` to aggregate the data of different types in a single structure

```
struct packet1_t
{
   // Packet1 specific data
   ......
}

struct packet2_t
{
   // Packet2 specific data
   ......
}

struct packet_t
{
    int common_id;
    union
    {
        struct packet1_t packet1;
        struct packet2_t packet2;
        ......
    }
} packet;
```

Now, based on the ID you can pick the correct type from the union:

```
int do_something_with_packet(packet_t packet)
{
    switch (packet.common_id)
    {
        case 1:
            do_something_with_packet1(packet.packet1);
            break;
        case 2:
            do_something_with_packet2(packet.packet2);
            break;
        ..................
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: I see, so unions are not solving my problem. my function `dispatch_packet` was about to work without knowing the packet types. it was supposed to be generic

Comment: The `do_something_with_packet` is generic.

Comment: At some point you have to know what the actual type. But up to that point you can keep generic as `do_something_with_packet` is doing.

Comment: @lordjj - If you start using a cast, you are probably doing something wrong. When you think about using a cast - have another think about the design

Comment: I see, this is not really that kind of genericity I was looking for >< I'll edit my topic, second

Comment: Finally, I could replace the union by a void *, and my packet_t would be simply a wrapper..

Comment: Why do you need `void` ? Everywhere you cast you can replace it with proper type picked from the union.

Comment: I'm making something like a library and my code should work without knowing any type u know

Comment: The trick is to avoid void pointers. Use the compiler and its abilities to find out errors in your code.Switch on all warnings etc.

Comment: Well just use the facade pattern.

Comment: But you know the set of possible protocols?

Comment: of course.. but is that really important, I don't get you

Comment: Then you can define `packet1_t`, `packet2_t` and so on precisely, can't you? It's not about working with unknown type, it's about working with one of the known types.

Comment: "Everywhere you cast you can replace it with proper type picked from the union" Then you have to maintain that union, which can turn into a dependency hell rather quickly.

Comment: I see but but I dont have knowned types since I dont have any built packets on my lib. My code is used by some users that define their packets and handlers in a upper scope

Comment: @n.m. Indeed. It would depend on the size of the project and the chosen style. Apparently the OP might choose the perfectly legit `void` option. It's just the question was about using `unions` :)

Comment: @lordjj If you have some types to cast into - then you have these types. If you don't - then ok, you need a different approach. Which would involve the requirement from user to provide some interface functions together with the types.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for you help, the other answer is ok.. Finally, my sample code worked and I didnt know it..

Comment: I will specify in my doc that `int common_id` is necessary on each packet header

Comment: I didn't expect that code worked at all.. Else I would have tried