# Memory alignment in C struct

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

I was going though memory alignment section of [C FAQs](https://c-faq.com/struct/align.esr.html#:%7E:text=struct%20%7Blong%3B%20char%3B%20short%7D%20would%20have%201%20byte%20of%20padding%20after%20the%20char%2C%20be%20the%20same%20size%20as%20example%207%2C%20and%20have%20no%20trailing%20padding.:%7E:text=struct%20%7Blong%3B%20char%3B%20short%7D%20would%20have%201%20byte%20of%20padding%20after%20the%20char%2C%20be%20the%20same%20size%20as%20example%207%2C%20and%20have%20no%20trailing%20padding) and found:

> struct {long; char; short}
> would have 1 byte of padding after the char, be the same size as example 7, and have no trailing padding.

Why is there padding after char? Why not after short?

I went though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) similar question but its still not clear to me.
In [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435841/memory-alignment-in-c-structs) a user mentioned :

> it aligns to the largest alignment of any item in the struct

But here largest item in the struct is `long` so do we then see next largest alignment while aligning smaller items?

Can someone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: This question settles it down https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: What is unclear?  An extra byte is probably placed after the char so that the short will be 2-byte aligned.  The whole thing is 8-bytes, which is already 4-byte aligned, so no trailing padding is required to get it to fit in arrays.

Comment: @Max 'Why is there padding after char? Why not after short?' This was unclear, its mentioned in the question. 
"so that the short will be 2-byte aligned"
Whichever answer I went though didn't mentioned this requirement/need. Link by Fra93 made it clear.
Thanks