# Access to class member by increment operator

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

I have a class, for example:

```
class Vector
{
    float x, y, z
};
Vector v;
```

And a pointer:

```
float *c = &v.x;
```

Will it be works correctly, when I'll use increment operator for access to y and z members?

P.S. Bad style to do by this way, but it's sport interest.

Comment: you can try it and you'll have the answer :)

Comment: @RedaBalkouch that's not at all how C++ works.

Comment: the code is working in my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it be works correctly, when I'll use increment operator for access to y and z members?

No. Undefined behavior. You can't perform pointer arithmetic across objects and you can't guarantee struct padding.

You can do stuff like this though:

```
class Vector
{
    float v[3];
    int& x() { return v[0]; }
    int  x() const { return v[0]; }
    // and so on ...
};
```

Comment: Is it? Can you provide a reference? (consider his exact example, where `Vector` is a POD.)

Comment: Why is "undefined behavior"?
More detailed answer please, or link.

Are the members sometimes separated in memory?

Thanks for code, it is obviously

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Two reasons: struct padding and pointer arithmetic rules. I'll look for a reference.

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the answer.

Comment: I've found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c).
Thanks for all.