# the size of struct which has datentype enum and pointer

Tags: c++, struct, enums, sizeof

I use the function `sizeof()`  to get the size of a struct. The result shows 40. I think that should be 56. 
 And if I delete `PicFormat   m_eformat;`, the size is still 40.  If I delete `PicFormat   m_eformat;` and `Framerate   m_eFramerate;` at the same time,  the size is 32. I do not know why.
The code is below:

"capstruct.h"

```
    enum PicFormat
    {
        PIC_JPG  = 0,            
        PIC_RGBA = 1,           
        PIC_RGB  = 2            
    }; 

    typedef enum 
    {
        RATE_30_HZ  = 0,
        RATE_25_HZ  = 1,
        RATE_20_HZ  = 2,
        RATE_15_HZ  = 3,
        RATE_7_5_HZ = 4
    } Framerate;

    struct sCaptureStruct
    {
        unsigned char   m_mac[6];             
        unsigned long long  m_iHWtime;
        unsigned long long  m_iNbr;
        PicFormat       m_eformat;             
        Framerate       m_eFramerate;
        unsigned int    m_iImageSize;
        unsigned char * m_pBuffer;
    };
```

main.cpp

```
#include "capstruct.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    sCaptureStruct s;
    int n = sizeof(s);
    cout<<n<<endl;

}
```

Comment: [Other relevant reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c)

Comment: unless you change compiler option, I think size is always a multiple of 8 (bytes). So that's why removing one attribute may no change the size. Can you detail why you expect size to be 56 instead of 40?

Comment: @jpo38 the size depends on the system(on x86 it will be 4byte alignment)

Comment: Why does it matter to you? Let the compiler figure out how to align the members. Things can get really interesting if your `struct` becomes a polymorphic type.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that by following the provided links....;-)

Comment: @jpo38 because there are 7 members in this struct. and the size is 7*8 =56. Am I right?

Comment: No, not everything has a size of 8.

Comment: Why you think every member will use 8 byte?
The standard doesn't define the size of specific types anyways.

Comment: With padding in parentheses, it'll probably look something like: 6(2)+8+8+4+4+4+4. But this will vary with architecture and implementation.

Comment: Note that `unsigned char` and  `char` has a size of 1 byte (8bits), int may have different sizes, pointer address is either 5 or 8 bytes (depending on plateform: 32bits or 64bits).....and `sizeof` is in bytes....your 56 evaluation is wrong.

Comment: @Melkon: corrected by comment, you may remove yours (I'll then remove this one ;-))