# Size of struct is more than expected

Tags: c++, memory, struct

I already read this question: [struct padding in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c) and this one [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

and I know this isn't standardized but still I believe it's a legit question.

Why is the size of this struct 16 on a x64 system?

```
struct foo { char* b; char a;};
```

The effective size would be 8 + 1 = 9, but I know there's padding involved. Anyway I thought `a` would only be padded to reach the size of an `int`, i.e. with other 3 bytes giving a total of 12 bytes.

Is there any reason why the specific compiler (gcc) thought it should have 16 bytes as a size?

Wild guess: is it possible that the biggest type (e.g. double or in this case x64 pointer) will dictate the padding to use?

Comment: It is an implementation detail that we really can't answer.

Comment: Did you read the first sentence of the first answer: *"This is because of padding added to satisfy alignment constraints."*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Likely the compiler is aligning the struct on an 8-byte word boundary to improve access speed. A struct size of 9 is probably going to slow down the CPU quite a bit with unaligned accesses (plus the stack pointer should never be on an odd address). A size of 12 (3 padding bytes), would work, but some operations, like the FPU operations, prefer an alignment of 8 or 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of memory alignment. By default memory is not aligned on one bye order and this happens. Memory is allocated on 4-byte chunks on 32bit systems.

You can change this behavior by setting `__attribute__((packed, aligned(x)))` when you define your structure. By this memory is allocated on `x-byte` chunks.

Comment: Question: is it allocated in 8-byte chunks on x64 systems?

Comment: Dynamically-allocated memory has alignment suitable for any type, which in practice means the most restrictive type. Pointers should be 8-byte aligned on x86_64, so dynamically-allocated memory should be at least 8-byte aligned.

Comment: As far as I know memory alignment is also 4bytes for x86_64, but for stack boundary and as Useless has mentioned for pointers its 8bytes.