# Why is getting extra bytes in a convertion from Struct to array bytes?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, visual-studio-2015, memcpy

I have an issue with C++ and VS-2015 with the next structure:

```
struct HEADER
{
    char BRI;
    char crv_lenght;
    __int16 crv;
    char messagetype;
};
```

**The size of this structure is 5 bytes**, but when it is converted to an array of bytes the resulting array **has a size of 6 bytes**.

The way that i used to convert the struct to array is using memcpy is:

```
HEADER hdr;

hdr.BRI = 0x08
hdr.crv_lenght =0x02;
hdr.crv = 0;
hdr.messagetype = 0x04;

char* buffer;
buffer = new char[sizeof(HEADER)];
memcpy(buffer, tmpBuff, *size);
```

After coverting the struct to an array, the buffer shows an extra byte (`0xcc`), that appears after the *crv* field:

*DEBUG  DATA    HEX (Bytes  1-6) [08 02 00 00 **cc** 04]*

But, when i change the struct to use `char[2]` instead of `__int16`, like this:

```
struct HEADER
{
    char BRI;
    char crv_lenght;
    char crv[2];
    char messagetype;
};
```

The resulting array size is **5 bytes**, removing the extra byte:

*DEBUG  DATA    HEX (Bytes  1-5) [08 02 00 00 04]*

I found a way to "fix" this issue is using the directive `#pragma pack(push,1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)`, like the sample below:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct HEADER
{
    char BRI;
    char crv_lenght;
    __int16 crv;
    char messagetype;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

**So, the main questions is:** For the compiler of C/C++ with VS-2015, this behaivor is expected and why it needs to use the `#pragma pack` directive?

Additional information:

- The OS Windows 2012 r2.
- Visual Studio 2016, version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.
- Language: C++11
- The project type is a Console App.
- This behavior appears in both x86 and x64.

Comment: Compilers will align and pad data structures for performance and other reasons. `c++` allows this and has to since some hardware requires alignment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c