# C++ sizeOf nested structs

Tags: c++, memory-management, struct, byte, padding

I've got a memory management problem. Since i'm working in a **constant sized buffer of bytes**, I need my data as compact as possible.

I need to check the size of a struct that has another struct inside of it. Here's the code:

```
struct CommonData
{
    //common data
    uint64_t a; // 8B
    uint64_t b; // 8B
    uint64_t c; // 8B

    uint32_t d; // 4B

    uint8_t e; // 1B

    uint8_t f; // 1B
};

struct AllData
{
    //specific data
    uint8_t arr[15]; //15B

    //common data
    CommonData commonData; //30B
}
```

Normally I would think that sizeOf(AllData) would be 30 + 15 = 45 B but the compiler says it is 48. Yes, I kind of know about memory paddings and yes I know that is the "issue" here.
Is there a way I could rearrange my data in order to get rid of those padding 3 bytes because memory is of high importance here.

**NOTE: __attribute__((packed)) does not do the trick**

EDIT:

> > ## pragma pack(push, 1)
>
> .... ....
>
> > ## pragma pack(pop)

on both structs did the trick but I'm not sure how safe and reliable this option is

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just swap the member variables in `AllData`.  Here is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c

Comment: @NathanOliver i tried that first :)