# Are std::optional members stored contiguously?

Tags: c++, std, stdoptional

I suppose I'm a bit confused as to how exactly optional values are stored. When constructing a class or struct that contains `std::optional<T>` members, will these members be stored contiguously in memory or does optional allocate dynamically? For example, would the below struct be one contiguous block of memory?

```
struct Material
    {
        std::string name;
        std::optional<size_t> albedo;
        std::optional<size_t> normal;
        std::optional<size_t> metalness;
        std::optional<size_t> roughness;
        std::optional<size_t> ao; // ambient occlusion
        bool hasAlphaChannel = false;
    };
```

Comment: Aside from `std::optional` internal storage you still have the concern of [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c) that may result in your members being non-contiguous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`optional` is required to not use dynamic allocation.

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an object, not a pointer, even though operator*() and operator->() are defined.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

There is also the member variables of `optional` and also padding that can occur. so no, they are not necessarily contigous, but they are within the object you declare them in.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard `std::optional` is prohibited to use dynamic memory for their direct members.

One possible layout could for example be:

```
template<class T>
class optional
{
    bool engaged;
    union {
        T value;
        unsigned char reserved;
    };
};
```

Comment: `reserved` is unnecessary

Comment: The name is not optional in this context.

Comment: The entire member named `reserved` is unnecessary. `union { T value; }` is valid.

Comment: @yurikilochek Why use a union in the first place?

Comment: @Symlink Because the `T` might not have a default constructor. When placed inside a `union`, the `value` is not initialized unless explicitly initialized with `placement new` (or some other initialization procedure).