# Can I be sure a vector contains objects and not pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, stdvector

Can I be sure an `std::vector` (or, in general, any standard container) contains objects and not pointers to objects, no matter how complex the objects' class is, if it has constant size?

E.g.: in this simple case:

```
struct MyStruct { int a, b; };
std::vector<MyStruct> vs;
```

The resulting vector layout is:

```
[ ..., a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, ... ]
```

Does the Standard guarantees the same happens in this (or more complex) case(s), where the size of the structure is supposed to be constant:

```
struct MyStruct2 { float f[10]; };
std::vector<MyStruct2> vs2;
```

With layout:

```
[ ..., f1[0], f1[1], ..., f1[9], f2[0], f2[1], ..., f2[9], ... ]
```

instead of:

```
[ ..., *pf1, *pf2, ... ]
pf1 = [ f1[0], f1[1], ..., f1[9] ]
pf2 = [ f2[0], f2[1], ..., f2[9] ]
```

Comment: ... what's the real question here? The containers all let you obtain a reference to the object. Some hold on to them in a pre-defined layout, but why should that matter?

Comment: Even in your simple `MyStruct` case you cannot necessarily assume that `a2` immediately follows `b1` in memory because the compiler is [free to add padding to your struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c). The only assumption you can make is that element `[1]` is exactly one `sizeof(MyStruct)` offset from `[0]` for example.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` holds `T`s, `std::vector<T*`> holds `T*`s.

Comment: you can use type traits to do sfinae on it, maybe a create_vector function which only takes std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>... https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer

Comment: There are two separate points here, (1) `std::vector` will store the value with the `value_type` you ask for, according to the template parameter you provide (if you provide a pointer type `T*`, it store pointer types) (2) If you want to have a vector which cannot hold a pointer type, you can make a thin wrapper around `std::vector` and use SINFAE to block pointer types or remove the pointer from the type.

Comment: Vector that contains pointers is a vector that contains objects, because pointers themselves are objects.

Comment: The layouts are incorrect in both cases.  First one should be `[ ..., MyStruct_1, MyStruct_2, MyStruct_3, ... ]` and the second one should be `[..., MyStruct2_1, MyStruct2_2, MyStruct2_3, ...]`.

Comment: @Eljay - I just wrote how the objects' contents is placed in memory.

Comment: I know what you wrote.  What you wrote was incorrect.  It is incorrect on the DS9K platform.  It may be correct on your platform, but using that insider information to access or manipulate the data is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: @Eljay - The purpose of my question is not to know how to have direct access to the vector's elements, but to know how they are laid out in memory for performance considerations.

Comment: The objects are stored sequentially in memory.  You only get pointers-to-objects if you have a vector of pointers, in which case those pointers would be stored sequentially in memory.  (A pointer itself is an object.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++11 and onwards (C++03 *nearly* guarantees it), the data in a `std::vector` are contiguous with no gaps.

In particular if you have a pointer to an element in the `std::vector`, you can reach all other elements using pointer arithmetic.

Of course, pointer arithmetic works in `sizeof` units of your `struct`. And the `struct` itself may contain padding. The behaviour on attempting to reach a `b`, given a pointer to an `a` in your struct is undefined.

Comment: This is a better articulation of what I was trying to ramble about in the comments, +1

Comment: infamous exception `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: I think you arent actually answering the quesiton. As I understand the question OP wants to know whether they can use pointer arithmetics on the elements of `f` of the vectors elements to reach `f` of the next vectors elements, but there might be padding in `MyStruct2`