# On data members only order in a class

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is the order of data members only class (so many) counts
and quite influential in access efficiency ?

if yes, how is their logical reasoning
thanks much before

Comment: I think only the first member will be slightly faster to access than the others, because no offset is needed relative to the object's beginning

Comment: Member order can influence padding and alignment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397447/struct-padding-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: it's not worth thinking about it.

Comment: Unless you have explicit "efficiency" requirements, and you have measured that in an optimized build this really is one of the top-two bottlenecks, then it's really not something you need to bother with.

Comment: And what is the background for your question? What is the context? Why are you asking? If you have an underlying problem then please ask directly bout it instead.

Comment: Some processors can access a member field with one instruction.  The ARM series have instructions that can add an offset to an address, then load from the effective address; all in one instruction.

Comment: A speed efficient class has it's members aligned with the processor's addressing capabilities.  For example, for a processor that only fetches 32 bits, you want your members to be aligned on 32-bit boundaries.  Other alignments will increase the quantity of fetches that the processor makes.

Comment: Regarding the alignment note by @ThomasMatthews, compilers usually pick the most efficient alignment for your members on the target processor. Again, in almost all cases you never have to do anything.